# How to restrict user not to put any white space in specific filed in a asp.net form using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have a form where I am grabbing user input using Key value pair. I don't want user to put any empty white spaces in key. So I created an `Id="noWhite"` and trying to apply a jquery on this id. here is my code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Device Name:</label>
            <input asp-for="DeviceName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DeviceName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <br />

        <h3>Device Parameters:</h3>
        @for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input name="DeviceParameters.Parameters[@i].Key" class="form-control" id="noWhite" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Value:</label>
                <input name="DeviceParameters.Parameters[@i].Value" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        }
        <br />
        <h3>Firmware Gates:</h3>
        @for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input name="FirmwareGates.Parameters[@i].Key" class="form-control" id="noWhite" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Value:</label>
                <input name="FirmwareGates.Parameters[@i].Value" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        }

        <br />
        <h3>Modem Include List:</h3>
        @for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input name="ModemIncludeList.Parameters[@i].Key" class="form-control" id="noWhite" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Value:</label>
                <input name="ModemIncludeList.Parameters[@i].Value" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#noWhite").on("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which === 32)
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
}
```

But it works only for my first DeviceParameters key (name). Here is a screenshot. 
[image]

I am trying to restrict white spaces in name field of Device Parameters, Firmware Gates and Modem Include List. But My jquery is working for only the first name field but not for all.

How can I restrict user not to put any white spaces in any key(name) field?

Comment: You can't prevent a user to insert a space by checking the key one types. The user still can copy/paste

Comment: You have assigned the same ID "noWhite" to multiple elements. ID is meant to be unique and that is why only the first element is processed. Use class instead of id to identify which fields to be processed.

Comment: I would use regex in the entity to prevent whitespaces, something like `[RegularExpression(@"^[^\s]+$")]`

Comment: Thank you @Cid for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here could be the multiple Id's with the same name. The id's should be unique.  If you need to identify multiple elements you can use classes.

Example:

Instead of:

```
<input name="ModemIncludeList.Parameters[@i].Key" class="form-control" id="noWhite" />
```

just use this:

```
<input name="ModemIncludeList.Parameters[@i].Key" class="form-control noWhite" />
```

And then in your jquery, instead $("#noWhite") selector, use this selector $(".noWhite")

Notice that the "#" was replaced by "." . That's beacuse the # look up for Id's  and the dot look up for classes.

```
$(".noWhite").on("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.which === 32)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

The id of a field is **unique**, and **you are duplicating it** in the for loop, so thats why it only works on the first input, **instead of using an id, try using a class** 
example:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
            <input name="FirmwareGates.Parameters[@i].Key" class="form-control noWhite" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Value:</label>
            <input name="FirmwareGates.Parameters[@i].Value" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    }
```

And the javascript function is:

```
$(".m-input").on("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.which === 32)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to remove white spaces when user enters text:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#noWhite").on("keyup", function (e) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().toString().replace(" ",""));
        });
});

</script>
<input type="text" id="noWhite">
```

> This also works in mobile device